# Atomic типы в сравнении с примитивами - влияние на производительность

Tags: java, kotlin, производительность, atomic

Если сравнивать обычный примитивный тип (например, Boolean) и соответствующий атомарный тип (AtomicBoolean), будет ли какая-то просадка по проивзодительности, если использовать AtomicBoolean вместо Boolean даже там, где можно было бы обойтись без него, "просто на всякий случай"?